# Problems installing Android Studio on Mint 16

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to install Android Studio, I have downloaded the zip from the website, extracted it and am trying to run `./studio.sh` however this will not work and I get the following message:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=250m; support was removed in 8.0

Start Failed: Internal error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.ide.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:39)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:83)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/java/jre/lib/i386/libawt_xawt.so: libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1937)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1822)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1937)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1843)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1636)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1634)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1633)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1668)
    at java.awt.Cursor.<clinit>(Cursor.java:195)
    at javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit.<clinit>(HTMLEditorKit.java:623)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.<clinit>(UIUtil.java:96)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.start(PluginManager.java:71)
    ... 6 more


Also, an UI exception occurred on attempt to show above message:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Toolkit
    at java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Component.java:593)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:231)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:217)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:86)
```

When I do `java -version` I get:

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

and when I do `javac -version` I get:

```
javac 1.7.0_55
```

Would appreciate any help, been Googling for a couple of hours :(

Comment: Why are you using Mint 16? The JDK != JRE. Install a Java 8 JDK, also AFAIK Android still doesn't support Java 8. Finally, what is the output of `uname -m`?

Comment: It's an old laptop. 'uname -m' shows 'x86_64' and I have installed the Java 8 JDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the 64-bit of Java. You are currently running a 32-bit version. That's what the error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
               /opt/java/jre/lib/i386/libawt_xawt.so: libXrender.so.1:
```

is telling you. `i386` is 32-bit Java.

Comment: Yep that was it, I should stop trying to do stuff with computers at 1am.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was because lack of restarting debian linux after fresh install of openjdk-7-jdk. After restart Android Studio installs without errors.